# Which fields does Laravel expect for the user table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Laravel handles user authentication and stuff, which is fine, but its documentation is lacking.

All I can really do is experiment and when Laravel throws an exception, add the field it is expecting, but aren't there, to the user table, because Google or its documentation does not give me a single clue as to which fields Laravel expects to find in the user table.

Latest example;
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the `timestamps`. If you don't want and don't have fields `updated_at` and `created_at` then set on your User model `protected $timestamps = false;` and it will solve the problem.

This is not `User` model thing, all Eloquent models work like this.

Be sure to check http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: Ah, damn. That would explain why I could't find what I was looking for when looking specifically for the user table. Thanks.

Comment: I still have to wonder... Is there any kind of decent overview of what your database layout should look like for Laravel/Eloquent to be able to use it withour workarounds? For example as far as I can tell things like hasMany () only works when the field names are the way Laravel/Eloquent expects them to be. Also, what about data types and field lengths for `created_at`, `updated_at`, `remember_token`, ...?

Comment: It's not about workarounds. Read the docs, check the API http://laravel.com/api/ ask in IRC #laravel. It's all out there. `hasMany` takes 3 parameters where you can define field names as you need http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships